# Multiple Identical Options in Switch Statements

Tags: javascript

It's the first time I'm using switch statements in Javascript and I've found a lot of difficulties while learning this through FreeCodeCamp. The question is the aforementioned: "Write a switch statement to set the answer for the following ranges:
1-3 - "Low"
4-6 - "Mid"
7-9 - "High".

I've tried to solve this problem by executing this code!

```
function sequentialSizes(val) {
  var answer = "";
  // Only change code below this line
switch(val) {
  case 1 && 2 && 3:
  case 4 && 5 && 6:
  case 7 && 8 && 9:
    answer = "Low", "Mid", "High";
    break;
}


  // Only change code above this line
  return answer;
}
```

I don't understand why the following Code is not functioning from my expectation. I'd like to know what the mistake was! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sequentialSizes(val) {

        var answer = "";
  
        if(val<=3){answer='low';}

        else if(val>3&&val<=6){answer='mid';}

        else{answer='high';}
  
        return answer;

}

document.write(  sequentialSizes(5) )
```

switch case statements are not suitable with operators.

better to use above code with `if` `else` statements

Comment: Thanks also. I really wanted to also know if Logical Operators are used in switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

Case statements don't work that way.  Try this:

```
switch(val) {
  case 1: 
  case 2:
  case 3:
    answer = "Low"
    break;
  case 4:
  // etc.
}
```

**Further Reading**
[Javascript 'switch' Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)